# mod_rewrite to download - makes suspicous looking file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, download

I decided to try and use mod_rewrite to hide the location of a file that a user can download.

So they click on a link that's directed to "/download/some_file/" and they instead get "/downloads/some_file.zip"

Implemented like this:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+)/?$ downloads/$1.zip [L]
```

This works except they when the download progress appears I'm getting a file "download" with no extension which looks suspicious and the user might not be aware they are supposed to unzip it.  Is there a way of doing this so it looks like an actual file? Or is there a better a way I should be doing this?

To provide some context/reason for hiding the location of the file.  This is for a band where the music can be downloaded for free provided the user signs up for the mailing list.

Also not I need to do this within .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the filename by sending the `Content-disposition` header:

https://serverfault.com/questions/101948/how-to-send-content-disposition-headers-in-apache-for-files

Comment: Ok based on this and a bit of googling I've tried:

    RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+)/?$ downloads/$1.zip [L,T=application/zip]

But it still doesn't work

Comment: More info. I'm doing this from .htaccess
so this example using LOCATION doesn't work

Comment: Setting the `filename` is the important part. Otherwise the browser determines the filename from the URL. Another approach is to use an URL that looks like a filename, e.g. `download/some-secret-value/filename.zip` and redirect that to the actual file.

Comment: Thats a very good point.  I just posted a solution using php but this seems neater.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I believe that I'm restricted as to what headers I can set using .htaccess

So I have instead solved this using php.

I initially copied a download php script found here:
[How to rewrite and set headers at the same time in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364848/how-to-rewrite-and-set-headers-at-the-same-time-in-apache)

However my file size was too big and so this was not working properly.

After a bit of googling I came across this: http://teddy.fr/blog/how-serve-big-files-through-php

So my complete solution is as follows...

First send requests to download script:

```
RewriteRule ^download/([^/\.]+)/?$ downloads/download.php?download=$1 [L]
```

Then get full filename, set headers, and serve it chunk by chunk:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['download']){
  $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'media/downloads/' . $_GET['download'] . '.zip';
}

define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024); // Size (in bytes) of tiles chunk

// Read a file and display its content chunk by chunk
function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
      return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }   
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }
    return $status;
}

$save_as_name = basename($file);   
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: disposition-type=attachment; filename=\"$save_as_name\"");

readfile_chunked($file); 
?>
```